# Jquery- calculate average of column "values" and put it in each td of another column

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Let's say i have a table like this:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="selection">
    <th>Values</th>
    <th>Average</th>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td></td>       
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td>0.9</td>
            <td></td>       
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td></td>       
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td></td>       
        </tr>  
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to calculate average of column "values" and put it in each td of the average column using Jquery. The result shoud be like this picture:

[image]

Please note that i filter results in the table with a search box and the number of rows will change each time the user searches.

Comment: xmm please show to us some of your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var sum = 0,
    count = -1,
    all = $('#selection > tbody > tr');
all.each(function() {
    sum += +$('td:eq(0)', this).text();
    count++;
});
all.find('td:eq(1)').text((sum / count).toFixed(3));
```

***[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/ujA7g/5/)***

#### Note

`+$('td:eq(0)', this).text()`, here the beginning `+` sing convert the text to number.

Comment: I was trouble with rowcount and now i have the solution. thank you.
just for knowing more is there any methods for controlling the decimals?. for example display average column with 2 decimals?

Comment: @DavidPeterson yup.. just change the `toFixed(2)`, this will show 2 decimal values

Answer (score 1):

```
var sum = 0, rows = $('#selection tbody tr');

rows.each(function() {
  sum += parseFloat($(this).children('td').eq(0).text());
});

rows.each(function() {
  var tds = $(this).children('td'), value = parseFloat(tds.eq(0).text());
  $(this).children('td').eq(1).text((value/sum).toFixed(3));
});
```

***[The working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/YJmFY/)***